# SSH authentication error even with right passphrase

Tags: ssh, web, cpanel

if a passphrase can open a private key file then isn't it the passphrase to login in my ssh terminal window. It says bad passphrase every time I try to use my password. It successfully opened the private key file in cpanel of my website though.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is most likely that you are attempting to use a passkey file that isn't of the same type/make.

An example of this, which may not be exactly the same as yours, but is a solid example is when a user attempts to create a private-key with puttygen, then "ssh-add" this key to an open-SSH agent (such as git bash).  Attempting to run:

```
git-add private-key-name.ppk
```

will result in the following error (which you have described):

```
Badd passphrase, try again for private-key-name.ppk:
```

and it will continue to give this error repeatedly, even though you are typing in the correct password.

To help troubleshoot your issue more, could you please add the following information to your post, or to a comment on my response?

```
What program you are attempting to use to make the connection (ie. openSSH in git Bash, putty/plink.exe, or other)
The exact steps you took from the beginning (starting at step 1 - installation).
```

Thanks,
u353

Answer (score 1):

Try running ssh in your terminal in verbose mode with a -v flag to see if you can isolate the problem. Hope this will help!